# scipy.optimize.shgo ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function `y(x,T,p)` to get the coefficients `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`. The data for `y`,`x`,`T`,`p` are known. With a global optimizer I want to find a good starting point. `shgo` seems to be the only one that accept `constraints`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import shgo

# test data
x = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,1])
T = np.array([300,300,300,300])
p = np.array([67.2,67.2,67.2,67.2])
y = np.array([30,50,55,67.2])

# function
def func(pars,x,T,p):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = pars
    return x*p+x*(1-x)*(a+b*T+c*T**2+d*x+e*x*T+f*x*T**2)*p

# residual
def resid(pars):
    return ((func(pars,x,T,p) - y) ** 2).sum()

# constraint: derivation is positive in every data point
def der(pars):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = pars
    return -p*((3*f*T**2+3*e*T+3*d)*x**2+((2*c-2*f)*T**2+(2*b-2*e)*T-2*d+2*a)*x-c*T**2-b*T-a-1)

con1 = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun':der})

# minimizer shgo
bounds = [(-1,1),(-1,1),(-1,1),(-1,1),(-1,1),(-1,1)]
res = shgo(resid, bounds, constraints=con1)
print("a = %f , b = %f, c = %f, d = %f, e = %f, f = %f" % (res[0], res[1], res[2], res[3], res[4], res[5]))

# plotting
x0 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.dpi = 80
ax.plot(x,y,'ro',label='data')
for i,txt in enumerate(T):
    ax.annotate(txt,(x[i],y[i]))
ax.plot(x0, func(res.x, x0, 300,67.2), '-', label='fit1')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

With this I am getting `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I do not know what that Error means and other threads with the same Error does not realy help me to understand. When I use a local minimizer (`scipy.optimize.minimize` with the method `cobyla`) the error does not appear.

Can someone help me to understand my problem or even help to fix it?
Thanks

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo_lib\triangulation.py", line 759, in __getitem__
    return self.cache[x]
KeyError: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.../test.py", line 70, in <module>
    res = shgo(resid, bounds, constraints=con1)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 423, in shgo
    shc.construct_complex()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 726, in construct_complex
    self.iterate()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 869, in iterate
    self.iterate_complex()
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo.py", line 890, in iterate_hypercube
    self.g_args)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo_lib\triangulation.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.n_cube(dim, symmetry=symmetry)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo_lib\triangulation.py", line 172, in n_cube
    self.C0.add_vertex(self.V[origintuple])
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo_lib\triangulation.py", line 767, in __getitem__
    index=self.index)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_shgo_lib\triangulation.py", line 681, in __init__
    if g(self.x_a, *args) < 0.0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: If you would like to test a different optimizer other than shgo, you can try implementing a "brick wall" within the function to return a large error - say, 1.0E10 -  if any given constraint is violated. While the initial parameter estimates must be within the constraints to allow the optimizer to begin, this simple technique can sometimes be quite useful in practice.

Comment: It would help if you showed the error traceback, so we can (and you) can see where the error occurs.  An error like this occurs when an array is used in a simple True/False test.  I suspect is has to do with the `con1` constraint, if for example `def` returns an array rather than a single value.  But we really need the traceback.

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that `der` returns an array instead of a scalar value. Changing

```
con1 = ({'type':'ineq', 'fun':der})
```

to

```
con_list = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: der(x)[i_out]} for i_out in range(T.shape[0])]
```

removes the error. This transforms each output of `der` into its own inequality constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since your constraints are all written so that `der(x)>=0`, one can simply keep the definition of oyur constraint with vector output and then fetch the minimum of the outputs, i.e., take a scalar value constraint `x -> \min (der(x))`.